# Виртуальные поля free pascal

Tags: ооп, freepascal

Есть ли возможность создавать в freepascal виртуальные или абстрактные поля? А ещё лучше виртуальные абстрактные и статические поля. Как их описать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "полями"? Свойства, методы?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: Поля это поля, не свойства и не методы. 

"Абстрактное поле" выглядит совершенной бессмыслицей. Статические [можно](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse31.html#x67-770006.1).

Comment: Ну бессмыслица и наводит на мысль, что "поля" это что-то не обязательно поля.

Comment: вообще вопрос можно ли их создавать. а не имеет это смысл или нет. 
это мне понадобилось для того чтобы в классе родителе определить метод который бы использовал эти абстрактные или виртульные переменные (или поля) а в каждом дочернем классе (потомке) они бы переопределялись под соответствующие нужды . сори если чтото неправильно или непонятно написано.

Comment: Помог бы небольшой пример того, что вы хотите достичь. Абстрактными (без реализации в базовом классе) и виртуальными (переопределяемыми в потомке) могут быть методы, которые в потомке могут работать с наследуемыми полями.

Статические поля как и статические (классовые) методы, это несколько другая тема, вероятно не относящаяся к решаемой проблеме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте подумаем, а есть ли смысл в абстрактном поле? Это должно быть поле с описанием (с этим проблем нет), но без реализации (а вот это для поля сложнее).

Но если представить себе поле как свойство, то все реально. Можно ведь сделать setter getter абстрактными:)

Аналогично можно сделать и виртуальные поля (хотя, если по делу, то абстрактные поля должны быть виртуальными, иначе их будет сложно переопределить).

Сами методы наиболее правильно описывать в разделе protected.